# Включить в SurfaceView подсветку по краям в конце прокрутки как у ListView

Tags: android

В моем приложении используется SurfaceView, внутри которого динамически создается рисунок. Рисунок этот можно двигать (т.е., прокручивать), я знаю его размеры и запрещаю прокрутку дальше его границ. Но хотелось бы сделать, чтобы когда прокрутка заканчивается у SurfaceView подсвечивался край. Точно также как если ListView прокрутить в конец списка у него подсветится нижний край (желтым, синим или белым, в зависимости от версии Android).

Насколько я вижу, в [исходниках View](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/master/core/java/android/view/View.java) есть некая инициализация этого процесса. Но мне совершенно непонятно, как его вызывать, когда достигается граница.

Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Может быть можно просто самому нарисовать такую анимацию у нужного края? Как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При достижении границы можно создать поверх изображения ImageView например и заполнить нужным градиентом. За появление и исчезание отвечает Alpha анимация. Это первое что пришло на ум, и вполне возможно что есть более рациональное решение. Вот статья про анимацию [тык.](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/animation/alpha.php)